# exe file doesn't work properly (nothing happens)

Tags: python, python-3.x, cx-freeze

When I compile my file (snake.py) to exe, the output file (exe file) doesn't work.
I thought this may be as a result of the error that occurs during compiling:

```
missing modules:
? _frozen_importlib imported from importlib
```

[image]

Any ideas??

```
import sys
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable

base = None
if sys.platform == "win32":
      base = "Win32GUI"

setup(
    name = "simple_PyQt4",
    version = "0.1",
    description = "Sample cx_Freeze PyQt4 script",
    options = {"build_exe" : {"includes" : "atexit" }},
    executables = [Executable("hello_qt.py", base = base)])
```

Comment: What tool do you use to "compile" exe?

Comment: What error does the exe give? How exactly it "does not work"?

Comment: What is your setup for building exe? Can you build "hello_world.py" successfully? Can you build something like "hello_qt.py" successfully?

Comment: I use cx_freeze.here's my setup,no rmatter what I compile(even a simple hello_qr.py), the exe output doesn't work.won't get any errors,I mean nothing just happen when I try to open the exe file:import sys

from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable

base = None
if sys.platform == "win32":
    base = "Win32GUI"

setup(
        name = "simple_PyQt4",
        version = "0.1",
        description = "Sample cx_Freeze PyQt4 script",
        options = {"build_exe" : {"includes" : "atexit" }},
        executables = [Executable("hello_qt.py", base = base)])

Comment: Do you use Python 2.x or Python 3.x?

Comment: OK, updated the answer to Python 3.3.

Answer (score 1):

I use `PySide`, but it should be almost equivalent to your PyQt.

I have this code `hello_pyside.py`:

```
import sys
from PySide.QtCore import *
from PySide.QtGui import *

class Window(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        QWidget.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)

        self.button = QPushButton("Test", self)
        self.button.setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy.Expanding, QSizePolicy.Expanding)

        self.layout = QHBoxLayout()
        self.layout.setContentsMargins(5, 5, 5, 5)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.button)

        self.setLayout(self.layout)
        self.show()

app = QApplication(sys.argv)
win = Window()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

I call this script installed with `cx_freeze`:

```
c:\Python33\Scripts\cxfreeze.bat hello_pyside.py --target-dir=Bin/pyside --base-name=Win32GUI --target-name=hello_pyside.exe --include-modules=re --exclude-modules=Tkinter
```

And I get the directory containing:

```
_bz2.pyd
hello_pyside.exe
PySide.QtCore.pyd
PySide.QtGui.pyd
pyside-python3.3.dll
python33.dll
QtCore4.dll
QtGui4.dll
shiboken-python3.3.dll
unicodedata.pyd
```

This should work fine.